# Executing Command on child shell

Tags: perl, shell

Here is the updated question

**Script:**

```
open (my $pipe, "| ptsetenv.sh $ProductType $Release");

print $pipe "genidasack.py -v --alignment=mips64 -a -s $WORKSPACE/dbgen/ose_signals_ADA.sdt -o $WORKSPACE/$Product/\n";

close ($pipe);
```

**Command 2:**

```
ptsetenv.sh $ProductType $Release  # Sets Environment Variables and creates a Child Shell
```

**Command 3:**

```
genidasack.py -v --alignment=mips64 -a -s $WORKSPACE/dbgen/ose_signals_ADA.sdt -o $WORKSPACE/$Product/\n #this has to be executed on child Shell created by Command 2
```

Currently when i run the script within a perl script after first line child shell is invoked and script remains at child shell when type exit from child shell subsequent script lines are executed which is not what is needed!

**HERE ARE CONTENTS OF ptsetenv.sh**

```
 envsetup.py $*

 ./export_env.sh
```

export_env.sh is the script which basically creates the child shell

Let me know if you need contects of export_env.sh

**HERE ARE CONTENTS OF export_env.sh**

```
has_dir()

    {
                 if [ -d $1 ]; then
                     return 0
                else
                 return 1
                fi
           }
            has_dir $DXENVROOT
             if [ "$?" != "0" ]; then
                echo "Directory $DXENVROOT does not exist. Exiting the script."
                exit -1
            fi
 echo "Environment set to ${DXENVNAME} ${DXENVVERSTR}"

 echo $SHELL

 $SHELL

echo "Exiting ${DXENVNAME} ${DXENVVERSTR} shell"
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of the `ptsetenv.sh` script?

Comment: Please use the `{}` tool in the editor when posting code, so I don't always have to edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

This will run a sequence of commands in the child shell:

```
system("Command 1; python script; Command 2");
```

You can also do:

```
system("Command 1");
system("python script");
system("Command 2");
```

This avoids creating a shell process if there are no special shell characters in the commands.

UPDATE:

Now that you've clarified that the python script starts a subshell, here's how to send a command to it:

```
open (my $pipe, "| Command 1; python script");
print $pipe "Command 2\n";
close ($pipe);
```

Comment: let me try this in office tomorrow; but i think i tried something like this within perl script it didnt work

Comment: You'll have to provide more details about why it fails.

Comment: Issue is with the python script which i am getting from different department which basically sets some environment variables internally and creates a shell prompt and waits for next command (Command 2) to be executed over this shell

Comment: and i dont think second option provided will work as i have tried already this and once System("python script") is executed it comes out of the shell

Comment: Setting environment variables in a script doesn't affect the parent shell that runs it.

Comment: Ahh, didn't notice that you said that the python script creates a new shell prompt. Will update my answer.

Comment: you are oasis in the desert :) thanks have been breaking my head over this all day today .. let me try this will update the post with result

Comment: Tried it didnt work :( here is the actual script lines i am using  open (my $pipe, "| ptsetenv.sh $ProductType $Release");
 83         print $pipe "genidasack.py -v --alignment=mips64 -a -s $WORKSPACE/dbgen/ose_signals_ADA.sdt -o $WORKSPACE/$Product/\n";
 84         close ($pipe); it is bit complex than what i said above command 2 = "ptsetenv.sh $ProductType $Release" which actually sets some environment variables and creates a child shell and command 3 ="genidasack.py -v --alignment=mips64 -a -s $WORKSPACE/dbgen/ose_signals_ADA.sdt -o $WORKSPACE/$Product/" is what i have run on that child

Comment: **Script:**
open (my $pipe, "| ptsetenv.sh $ProductType $Release");
print $pipe "genidasack.py -v --alignment=mips64 -a -s $WORKSPACE/dbgen/ose_signals_ADA.sdt -o $WORKSPACE/$Product/\n";
close ($pipe);
<br/>
**Command 2:** "ptsetenv.sh $ProductType $Release"  --> **Sets Environment Variables and creates a Child Shell**
<br/>
**Command 3:** "genidasack.py -v --alignment=mips64 -a -s $WORKSPACE/dbgen/ose_signals_ADA.sdt -o $WORKSPACE/$Product/\n"
--> **this has to be executed on child Shell created by Command 2**
<br/>

Comment: Still can't read it. What part of "update your question" don't you understand?

Comment: Yesterday I asked you to post the ptsetenv.sh script.

Comment: Posted contents of ptsetenv.sh

Comment: OK, now post `export_env.sh`. How do you expect anyone to help if you don't show us the script that's doing the real work? We need to see how the shell is being invoked.

Comment: I can't see any reason why my answer doesn't work. The shell reads its commands from stdin, and the first script runs all the other scripts with stdin redirected to the pipe. Is it stopping before or after it prints `Environment set to`?

Comment: it exactly stops at $SHELL waiting for user input

Comment: No idea, unless you're using a strange shell that reads from /dev/tty instead of standard input. Earlier you said you were using a python script that sets environment variables and starts a shell. But now it appears that the python script is returning and then the shell is started. So the environment variables are lost when the python script finishes.

Comment: here is the sequence

1. ptsetenv.sh - calls envsetup.py

2. envsetup.py - creates export_env.sh at run time

when i the lines i have mentioned in the script manually it works

so basically at $SHELL it keeps waiting for user input :(

Comment: I give up, I can't see a reason why my solution doesn't work. Sorry.